# Добавить hover к блоку при помощи jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="choose-city clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">City 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Other city</a>
                    <ul class="cities-list clearfix">
                        <li><a href="">City 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">City 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">City 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">City 5</a></li>                            
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

В процессе родительский блок этого блока скрывается:

```
$('.header').stop(true).slideDown(400);
```

а сам блок клонируется с навешанными на него событиями и ставится на другое место:

```
var choose_city = $('.header_inner .choose-city').clone(true).addClass('cloned').hide().appendTo('.map-container').show('200').animate({
        'top': '20px',
        'left': '40px'
    }, 200);
```

И мне надо добавить hover, чтобы он работал и для исходного блока, и для клонированного. 
Не могу  понять, почему вот такой код у меня работает:

```
$('.choose-city > ul > li:eq(1)').hover(function () {
$(this).children('a').addClass('active');
var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
sub_menu.stop(true).slideDown(100, function () {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 200);
});
}, function () {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
    var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
    sub_menu.stop(true).slideUp(100, function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            'opacity': 0
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

а когда пытаюсь добавить hover вот так, то не работает:

```
$('body').delegate('$(".choose-city > ul > li:eq(1)")', 'hover', function ( event ) {
if (event.type === 'mouseenter') {
    console.log("test1");
    $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
    var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
    console.log('sub_menu');
    sub_menu.stop(true).slideDown(100, function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 200);
    });
} else {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
    var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
    sub_menu.stop(true).slideUp(100, function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            'opacity': 0
        }, 200);
    });
}
});
```

Почему?

Answer (score 2):

Решение http://jsfiddle.net/cuezpzru/6/

HTML

```
<div class="choose-city clearfix">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">City 1</a>
                <ul class="cities-list clearfix">
                    <li><a href="">City 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">City 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">City 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">City 4</a></li>                            
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Other city</a>
                <ul class="cities-list clearfix">
                    <li><a href="">City 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">City 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">City 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">City 8</a></li>                            
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.choose-city ul:first-child>li').delegate($("a"), 'mouseenter mouseleave', function ( event ) {
    if (event.type === 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
        var sub_menu = $(this).find('ul.cities-list');
        sub_menu.stop(true).slideDown(100, function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            'opacity': 1
            }, 200);
        });
    } else {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
    var sub_menu = $(this).find('.cities-list');
    sub_menu.stop(true).slideUp(100, function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            'opacity': 0
        }, 200);
    });
}
    });
})
```

Comment: Не, тоже срабатывает не так, как надо, такой скрипт срабатывает при наведении вообще на тег `body`, а не на ссылку.

Comment: Опишите поточнее, как должно работать

Comment: Подменю должно появляться при наведении на ссылку, щас оно появляется когда просто двинешь мышкой по странице и не исчезает.

Comment: jquery какой версии стоит?

Comment: Полностью обновил ответ.

Comment: А можете обьяснить, какие-то преимущества дает использование `delegate`, как в вашем ответе, по сравнению с `$('.choose-city > ul > li:eq(1)').hover(function () {/*...*/});`.

Comment: Начиная с jQuery-1.7, данный метод считается устаревшим. Предпочтительным является методом .on().

При простом использовании события (hover, click и т.д.) вешается обработчик непосредственно на сам элемент, а при использовании delegate обработчик устанавливается, элементам, найденным внутри контейнера с помощью селектора
$(container).delegate(selector,.....

Прикрепил пример с событием click, с hover будет то же самое http://jsfiddle.net/r3njyL7L/